# Swift - Colour appears washed on device

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode, uicolor, xcode11

Using XCode's assets to store my colours and for some reason the actual colour on my device when I run the build of the app, is a really washed colour! No matter what I do, it doesn't look like it is meant to.
It colour doesn't seem to come out right. I have put in the hex value in the color set and all. 
It doesn't look as good as I want it to and I don't understand why it looks crappy on my device which is an IPhone XS Max. But this screenshot below looks a bit better? I am a bit lost. Any help would be appreciated.

[When I screenshot it, it looks normal. Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64X8a.png)

[This is how I set my colours.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hW27Q.png)

Answer (score 0):

Did you maybe check which color profile are you using? Maybe try using different profiles. You can change the color profile by clicking the gear icon on the color picker next to the "color type" dropdown.

What you want to achieve is to user the same color profile as the source of the color (the program where you are copying the colors).

Good options are usually P3 or sRGB. Be sure to set reset the color after changing the profile. Usually the color is updated with the color profile (color looks the same, but the hex/rgb value changes).

Play around with different values and see if it fixes the issue.

The image below demonstrates how to change the color profile.

[image: Color picker demonstrating the color profile selection button]